# Scroll View problems

Tags: ios, uiimage, orientation

I have scrollview that works fine in portrait.The problem is when i change it to landscape the images messed up. I need a automate method to do this stuff according to orientation.Thanks :D

Comment: Show some code? There's too little info to help you

Comment: - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];    
    self.imageArray = [[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:@"photo1.png",@"photo2.png",@"photo3.png",@"photo4.png",@"photo5.png",nil];
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<[self.imageArray count];i++){
        CGRect frame;
        frame.origin.x=self.scrollView.frame.size.width*i;
        frame.origin.y=0;
        frame.size=self.scrollView.frame.size;

Comment: UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:frame];
        imageView.image=[UIImage imageNamed:self.imageArray[i]];
        imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
        [self.scrollView addSubview:imageView];
    }
    
    self.scrollView.contentSize = CGSizeMake(self.scrollView.frame.size.width*[self.imageArray count], self.scrollView.frame.size.height);
    
}

Comment: (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation: (UIInterfaceOrientation)orientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
    
    if ((orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) || (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight)){
    }
    
    
}


#pragma mark - UIScrollView Delegate

-(void)scrollViewDidScroll:(UIScrollView *)sender{
    CGFloat pageWidth = self.scrollView.frame.size.width;
    int page=floor((self.scrollView.contentOffset.x  - pageWidth/2)/pageWidth)+1;
    self.pageControl.currentPage = page;
}

Comment: sorry for the code view...any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Try using autolayout to position your images relatively inside your scrollview. You won't need any additional methods to handle positions on rotation.
I recommend you using this library for a faster and easier syntax when positioning your views https://github.com/Masonry/Masonry.